# Runining xercesImpl on java 6

Tags: java, java-6, xerces

I am using xercesImpl.jar to create instance of DocumentImpl, 
when I am runing the application on java6 I get the following error :

> The java class could not be loaded. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (myClass) bad major version at offset=6

at first I saw there Is a problem with my jdk , but after reading about it a little more I read there is conflict in xerces-2_11_0.jar and jdk6.

What jars and in what versions should I add to the project to avoid this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using xercesImpl jar wothversion 2.11.0. you can find maven details as below :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should solve your conflicts.

Comment: Thanks , but it didn't solve the problem , I get the same error.

Comment: I am using jars :  activation , avalon-framework-cvs-20020806 ,batik ,dom , fop ,xercesImpl-2.11.0 , xml-apis . any idea how to solve the conflict in java 6 . (when I am runnig it from spring it works o.k.) .

Comment: can you check the external jar files added in your ide ? it may be working due to external jar in your classpath.